# Angular subscribing to route and route parameters

Tags: observable, angular-routing, angular5

Angular 5 application has a data service that returns products in the specified `category` and there's pagination.
Category is specified in routes as parameter. Pagination is and query parameter. Url's looks like this: `/category?page=2`. (category is a variable)

**Issue:**
the component is subscribed to both `queryParams` and `paramMap`. If only one is used, it's fine, but going from '/category?page=2' to '/anotherCategory' triggers both, which means that data gets pulled twice (and depending on which observable returns data first, this introduces unwanted results). Using `snapshot` doesn't work either in this case.

I haven't been able to find a best practice around how to solve this.

```
@Component({..}}

constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

ngOnInit() {

    this.route.queryParams.subscribe((params: Params) => {
        this.currentPage = params['page'];
        this.getData(this.category, this.currentPage);
    });

    this.route.paramMap.subscribe ((params: Params) => {
        this.category = params.get('categoryName');
        this.getData(this.category, this.currentPage);
    });
}
```

> note: the code is slightly modified and stripped for simplicity.

Comment: What happens when you just get the paramsMap?

Comment: @Gary, then I just have the categoryName, not the ?page=2

Comment: Ah got your point.

Comment: Can you try validating url subscribe/ change through observable some how or try the get pathFromRoot: ActivatedRoute[]

Answer (score 0):

Your doubt is very logical and we have to use both subscriptions here, as snapshots will not detect param changes for same route.

What we can do here is to check the Activated route in the getData function. So if the parameters to pull the data doesn't match with our route then we can simply return.

We will only get the data when both the parameters match with the activated route. The current params in the route can be checked by snapshot.

Let me know in case further clarification is required.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can use [`combineLatest`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/combinelatest.html) to create a single observable that fires when either route params or query params change:

`combineLatest(
      this.route.params,
      this.route.queryParams
    ).pipe(
      map(([params, qparams]) => {
        //do your stuff here
      })
    )`